# In java press key without frame (or frame in background)

Tags: background, mouse, keylistener

I created a program that controls the mouse using the keyboard. I implement KeyListener to a class I called Keyboard, and then I create a JFrame called frame that adds this keyboard class. Here's part of the code to explain what I'm doing:

```
class Keyboard implements KeyListener
{
    //Overrides key methods
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My problem is I want the program to run when the frame is not selected (or even better, without the frame). For example, when I select another window of another program (a browser, Word, etc) the mouse won't move when I use the keyboard. I have to select my program window to control the mouse.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.